# AngularStrap Typeahead with async call double popup

Tags: typeahead, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStrap Typeahead with an async call in my webapplication and i'm noticing a strange behaviour: when i select one entry from the list the selected value correctly displays in the typeahead, the popup disappears but shortly after a new popup comes out displaying only 1 entry, which is the one i already selected. 
This happens only with async calls, and this issue also happens on the 
[official angulastrap showcase page](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads).
Notice that the not-async calls are working properly.

Has anyone already faced and solved this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Comment: I think I found the issue for me. I was using ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' and the popup was reopening after 1 second. Are you using this as well?

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue for this: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/2159